# Gremlin query to group and count by multiple values

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

Having a schema like this one

`(Page {name})-[HAS]->(Link {date, clicked})`

I would like to retrieve records grouped by `Page.name` and `Link.date`, ordered by `Link.date` (desc)

Also, for each of these entry I want in the same record to know:

- the total number of Links having same Link.date
- the total number of Links having clicked == true

Something like this:

- page=Page1, date=2023-06-08, total=3, clicked=1
- page=Page2, date=2023-06-08, total=5, clicked=0
- page=Page1, date=2023-06-07, total=1, clicked=0

I've tried to use group and groupCount, succeeding in retrieving the records grouped by Page with the details of their Link.date and count:

`g.V().hasLabel('Page').as('p').outE().inV().as('l').group().by(select('p').by('name')).by(select('l').by('date').groupCount()).unfold()`

- ==>Page2={Thu Jun 08 00:00:00 CEST 2023=5}
- ==>Page1={Wed Jun 07 00:00:00 CEST 2023=1, Tue Jun 08 00:00:00 CEST 2023=3}

But I cannot understand how to aggregate again ('l') with a where clause and how to appropriately form the records in the way that i need.

Comment: It will help provide tested answers if you are able to update the question to include the `addV` and `addE` steps that build a sample graph.